# C# Session State Sql Server error catching

Tags: c#, sql-server, session-state

We have a web application use sessions InProc to store large amount of data like datasets etc.
We are thinking about changing sessions state from InProc to Sql Server, but we are using Sessions at so many places in the code and it is very hard to find. (application is too big).
I did make classes [Serializable], but there are some serialization errors occured. WE catch all the errors using Global.aspx by Application_Error, but it is hard to figure out where in the code or which element failed, so i can fix it. I am thinking is there any way to know this information.
I am using vS 2010.
Thanks,

Comment: `CTRL+F` "Session" Right-click "Find all references"

Answer (score 0):

Check the Call Stack in the visual studio.
Debug --> windows --> Call Stack

Comment: Because I can put breakpoints only at Global.aspx file, so on checking call stack, it is external code.

Answer (score 0):

Session is not the right place for big data like datasets. On every request it get deserialized, so big data results in bad performance.

Comment: I know but it is written earlier and i cannot change the whole process. Thanks for suggestion